# Inviting users through email

Tags: database, schema

I have an app that allows users to assign tasks to people not yet in the system.

Once I enter "share with some_user@example.com", the user will receive an email, and I will have to note somehow that I have a friendship pending with that user.

My friendship table is set up as follows:

user_id:integer, friend_id:integer, status:string

Scenario: adding a friend
Steve's user_id = 2, fred's user_id = 6
When a friendship is started, I add two rows to the friendships table:
(user_id, friend_id, status)
(2, 6, requested)
(6, 2, pending)

This covers the friendship from both sides.

My question is, what is a good practice for handling friendships with user's not yet signed up.

The way I did it thus far is to put an email in status (which doesn't feel right to me), and to send the invited user a link with a token in it. When the user clicks that link. they are pass a token in the url to the signup page. If, upon signup, my controller sees that token, I'll search the friendships table for friendships.status = "invited_user@email.com" and update that record to point to the newly created user's id.

This feels dirty to me (storing email addresses and searching them).

Another solution I just came up with is to create one side of friendship
(user_id = 3, friend_id = null, status ="invited")

and send an invite with a query_string http://www.myapp.com/sign_up?invited_by=john@email.com.

With that, I can find john's id by email, find friendships where user_id = john.id AND status = "invite" and update that with my newly created user_id:
(user_id = john.id, friend_id = invited.id, status = "accepted")

then create the other half of the friendship: 
(user_id = 36, friend_id = john.id, status = "accepted")

No messy token sending or embedding in the url (just invited by email as a query string).

If a user has multiple invites out, that doesn't really matter, as any record with the status of "invite" can be used, since we don't yet know the invited user's id.

Any thoughts or better practices?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your first solution isn't the best. Learned the lesson a long, long time ago to not get creative with database fields. They should be used for one purpose and one purpose only. (In other words, don't store an email in a status field. Store status and only status.)

The second solution seems to work.

What about introducing a new entity? You'd have users and pending_users. Two different tables, but you could still have a mapping between them.

At some point if the pending_user signs up, they can become a "real" user and be migrated to the users table.

It's a nice natural segmentation and I would imagine would make queries a little more intuitive - and it would remove the invited_by email from the URL.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Thank you for the insight.